# Compare strings doesn't work when I use syntax code equals, equalsIgnoreCase and compareTo

Tags: android, xml

Goal:
Compare the strings

Problem:
It doesn't work when I use the syntax code equals, equalsIgnoreCase and compareTo.

What is the part that am I missing?

Info:
*Im new in android

Thank you!

[image: Rightclick and select copy adress and paste it in the a new browser in order see the picture in a original size]

[image: Rightclick and select copy adress and paste it in the a new browser in order see the picture in a original size]

[image: Rightclick and select copy adress and paste it in the a new browser in order see the picture in a original size]

[image]

New picture:

[image]

---

```
    private String _EASY = "Easy", _MEDIUM = "Medium", _HARD = "Hard";

    public void calculateMath(View view)
    {
        TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvw_status);


        String a1 = status.getText().toString();
        String a2 = _EASY;



        if (status.getText().toString().equals(_EASY));
        {
            int ffsdf = 23;
        }


        if (a1.equals(a2));
        {
            int ffsdf = 23;
        }


        if (a1.equalsIgnoreCase(a2))
        {
            int ffsdf = 23;
        }


        if (a1.compareTo(a2) == 0)
        {
            int ffsdf = 23;
        }

  }
```

---

layout/activity_play.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="50sp"
        android:text="Easy"
        android:textSize="30sp" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="calculateMath"
        android:text="Calculate" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try printing out the return value of `compareTo`.

Comment: I have uploaded a new picture about the return value of compare

Comment: To confirm it's not a bug in Android Studio, can you add a print statement in each of the if statement's bodies?

Comment: Do you have a code that I can paste it?

Comment: if (a1.compareTo(a2) == 0)
        {
            int ffsdf = 23;
            System.out.println("Inside if statement!");
        }

Comment: Log or toast the value

Comment: Take a look at the new picture. The statement works.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the declaration of `ffsdf`. You have to declare it outside of `if` statement.

This will work

```
 private String _EASY = "Easy", _MEDIUM = "Medium", _HARD = "Hard";

public void calculateMath(View view)
{
    TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvw_status);


    String a1 = status.getText().toString();
    String a2 = _EASY;

    int ffsdf;

    if (a1.compareTo(a2) == 0)
    {
        ffsdf = 23;
    }

}
```

As to why this is happening, refer to this question [Why can't variables be declared in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444020/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: You solution works and I never have encountered this kind of problem when I do coding in C# . Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when trying to compare strings in the past. Try `Objects.equals(a1,a2)`, `.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

Objects.equals() just checks for nulls before calling .equals() so you don't have to do it.

You almost always want to use Objects.equals() when it comes to Strings in my opinion. 
You can find more information about the Objects class here: [Objects class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

CompareTo:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Best suited for numerical values in its default form, you would have to override it in order to compare Strings.Information about overriding can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)
(more information about the compareTo method can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)))

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!